# Powershell get laptop brand

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

Is there a way to get a laptops brand like acer, hp, samsung via powershell? I looked at get-wmiobject to no avail. I know this is probably a long shot.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: try checking [powershell command guide](http://ss64.com/ps/)

Answer (score 8):

Did you look at `Win32_ComputerSystem`?

```
Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_ComputerSystem -Property Manufacturer, Model
```

Comment: Ya, it returns Dell Inc. I'm looking for Acer.

Comment: @user2526047 uhh... So is it a Dell or an Acer?!?! If it's a Dell why would you expect Acer? Conversely if its an Acer why would it return Dell?

Answer (score 2):

That's *very *odd. Are you saying that WMI returns not just the wrong model but the wrong manufacturer? I've heard of cases where the wrong model was reported, but not the wrong manufacturer, and AFAIK there's no cross-pollination of hardware between Acer and Dell. This makes me wonder if you bought some cheap knock-off from the far east where the fake BIOS identification was accidentally mismatched with the fake external case. But if you're getting the wrong information from WMI, see if you can get it from the registry:

```
Get-ItemPropertyValue HKLM:\HARDWARE\DESCRIPTION\System\BIOS -Name SystemManufacturer
Get-ItemPropertyValue HKLM:\HARDWARE\DESCRIPTION\System\BIOS -Name SystemProductName
```

If that returns different information, also see what you get from this:

```
(Get-WmiObject Win32_BIOS).Manufacturer
```

I wouldn't surprised if it says Micro-Star International. :|

Comment: user2526047 Did this work for you, or did you get the same (incorrect) results?

Answer (score 1):

This works with all PowerShell versions, including PowerShell Core (>=6.x):

```bsh
Get-CimInstance Win32_ComputerSystem | Format-List Manufacturer, Model
```

`Get-WmiObject` is [no longer available in recent versions of PowerShell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/whats-new/breaking-changes-ps6?view=powershell-7#wmi-v1-cmdlets).